# When deploying meteor apps to non-meteor infrastructure, how can I maintain different environment configurations for third party login services?

Tags: environment-variables, meteor

When deploying meteor apps to Heroku or another non-meteor hosted infrastructure and using third party OAuth login service packages, such as [`accounts-facebook`](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api), one must concern himself with securely maintaining the API keys and API secrets for each third party login service.

How may I securely maintain environment specific secure information for different types of environments (for example, development, staging, and production) in that context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In maintaining a deployment strategy, where there are development, staging, and production environments, and code is moved through those layers, starting with dev boxes, and ending with production, one need to consider two things: not committing secure information to a VCS system like git, and ease of environment configuration maintenance.

One may consider using environment variables for the above use case.

For example, to configure `accounts-facebook`, you might write the following in your meteor application's `server/config.js`:

```js
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
  service: "facebook"
});

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
  service: "facebook",
  appId: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  secret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
});
```

The following lines are essential:

```
appId: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
secret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
```

`process.env` gets you access to all the environment variables.

Then, you may just set the environment variables `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` and `FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET` specific to your environment - dev, staging, or production.

Comment: I need to wait 2 days to do so :)